# How to change FileReferenceList browse title?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3

I am using FileReferenceList browse method. the window opened shows the following title:
"Select file(s) to upload by ". 
I would like to change this title - how can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only things you can change in this window are the [file filters/types](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileFilter.html) to be uploaded. All the other elements are OS dependent. Sorry.

Comment: I can't even change the machine name it displays in the title (after upload by..)?

Comment: Not even... As I said there is only one parameter available for `FileReference.browse`.